# Identify two National semiconductor transistors 506 220-0075, 452 220-0076

Tags: transistors, bjt, identification, npn, pnp

I am trouble shooting a power window amplifier circuit board for a Nissan Quest.

The circuit board is relatively small, it has a few active component, most of which can be identified by simply googling the markings.

However, there are these two transistors with National Semiconductor logos, but for the life of me I can't find any useful information about them:
[image: National Semiconductor 506 220-0075]

and 
[image: National Semiconductor 452 220-0076]

Comment: They are custom spec OEM part numbers ( proprietary ) So dont expect to find anything on them built to automotive standards.

Comment: If you need a replacement I might suggest NPN 2SD438

Comment: I measured each transistors using a DMM, one of them is NPN, the other is PNP, both seems to be in good working condition. I'll leave them be for now.

Comment: the best way is measure Vce(sat) and Ic. This ratio gives Rce which is the critical spec that must be met for some Ic/Ib ratio.